# $R$ is a ring with identity. Why from $f(1)=0$ it's concluded that $\forall r\in R; f(r)=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The original question is this:

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $\mathbb{C}$ the ring of complex numbers. Suppose $f,g:R\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are two ring homomorphisms such that for every $r$ in $R$, $|f(r)|=|g(r)|$. Prove that $f=g$ or $f=\bar{g}$.

I have assumed that $f\ne g$ and concluded that $f\ne 0 \ne g$. Now I want to say show that $f(1)=1=g(1)$; but I need to see how $f(1)\ne 0$. Some suggest that if $f(1)=0$, then $\forall r\in R; f(r)=0$, hence $f=0$ which is a contradiction. I want to see how they get to this conclusion.

Comment: presumably your ring homomorhpism doesn't necessarily take $1$ to $1$.  If $f(1) = 0$ then $f(r) = f(1 \cdot r) = f(1) f(r) = 0 \cdot f(r) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(r) = f(r.1) = f(r).f(1).$$
$f(1) = 0 \Rightarrow f(r) = 0 \forall r \in R$